# Duvida de como manipular (apagar atributo) de um Objeto ou Json em php

Tags: php, json

A ideia da aplicação é apartir da string criar um modelo de json

A string sempre é alterada mas respeitando a sintaxy que é como se fosse acessar os elementos e um objeto $var;
a partir da seguinte string:

```
$var->abreviacao
$var->array[0]->nome
$var->array[0]->idade
$var->id
$var->sala
```

Quero transformar em um json com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{
    "abreviacao":"none",
    "array":[
        {
            "nome":"none",
            "idade":"none",
        }
    ]
    "sala":"none",
    "id":"none"
}
```

Obs: O objeto *$var* não existe apenas a string existe

Pensei em construir um objeto e adicionar atributos com eval() porem ao criar um objeto da seguinte forma

```
$obj = (object) 'string aleatoria';
$obj->array[0]->nome="none";
$obj->array[0]->idade="none";
$obj->sala="none";
$obj->id="none";
echo json_encode($obj);
```

é criado um atributo indesejado

```
$var->scalar
```

Preciso ou apagar um atributo do json ou do objeto qualquer um dos dois serviria

Comment: Leia: https://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-json-em-php/26716

Comment: Tentou criar o objeto como `$obj = new stdClass();`? Assim o atributo `scalar` não é criado. De qualquer forma, não ficou muito claro para mim, vc recebe uma string com o código (`$obj->array etc...`)?

Comment: Isso mesmo eu recebo uma string com ose estivesse acessando o atributo de um objeto.
Sua dica deu certo obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

fiz como *hkotsubo* me indicou.

Para criar o objeto usei:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
```

ao invez de:

```
$obj = (object) 'string aleatoria';`
```

Assim o atributo scalar não é criado.